# Замена значения переменной apache nifi с помощью командной строки

Tags: cmd, apache-nifi

Можно ли заменить значение переменной в apache nifi с помощью командой строки ?

Answer (score 0):

Переменные окружения достпны в NiFi как variables, хотя и не отображаются нигде в UI.

Поэтому можно использовать `export varname=nifi` и потом в процессоре указать ${varname} там где поддерживается Expression Language Scope Variable Registry.